# One way ANOVA. Prove that second estimator yields larger value under alternative hypothesis.

Tags: statistics, anova

I am reading the topic on One way ANOVA from the text - Introductory Statistics by Sheldon Ross. To explain the concept of ANOVA, the author has found estimates of $\sigma^2$ using two different approaches and deduced that when the sample means are not equal, the variance found out from the second method is larger in value **( text shown in red in the second image)**.

How do I prove this is true? Hints quite appreciated! Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560390/one-way-anova-one-estimator-yields-larger-value-under-alternative-hypothesis/560426#560426)